# Shortcut to find imaginary part of analytic function given real part, without standard form of Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

I am supposed to find the imaginary part of the analytic complex function, which has real part:

$$e^{y^2-x^2}\cos(2xy)$$

and $z=x+iy$. I know that the answer is $e^{-z^2}+ic$. This can be verified using Cuuchy-Riemann equations:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} 
$$

There is a much shorter way to arrice to the answer than just applying CR, I believe. I remember we considered derivatives with respect to $z$ and $z^*$, but I don't remember the whole method, but it was a huge shortcut compared to CRs in the form above.

How can I arrive to the imaginary part of the analytical complex function with real part $$e^{y^2-x^2}\cos(2xy)$$, without much algebraic juggling?

Comment: Take the imaginary part of $e^{-z^{2}}$ .

Comment: The only shortcut that I can see is to make an educated guess, and $e^{-z^2}$ seems natural since $$y^2-x^2 - 2ixy = -(x+iy)^2 = -z^2,$$ so that $$  e^{y^2-x^2} \cos(2xy) = e^{\Re(-z^2)} \cos(\Im(-z^2)) = \Re(e^{-z^2}).$$

Comment: Thanks. I see that if we make an educated guess, that works. How do I know though, that my guess is unique, and there is no arbitrary constant in it (apart from the additive ic), which I have not found?